# Appium:Andriod Emulator Drop Down not working after connecting with VPN

Tags: selenium, android-studio, automation, appium, appium-android

Scenario:My app is working fine in mobile device after connecting with NordVPN.When the same App When I execute in Andriod Studio emulator after connecting with NordVPN,the App is launching but at one of the page the dropdown is showing error,rather than the values.

Requesting if someone can help me to resolve the issue or can provide any supportive link.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which dropdown doesn't work? I do not think anyone can help you without knowing the details.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently find the solution by first wiping out the data and then reboot refactory the android emulator in android studio.